'node-pre-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command
My project has been working fine untill I made a pull from the backend dev branch (I'm not involved directly with it) which I integrate with the frontend. I noticed some changes to the package.json file and I ran npm install to update the file and since then I've be getting the error: 'node-pre-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command
I tried running the project using npm run dev and I was getting; 'ts-node-dev' is not recognized as an internal or external command. None of the scripts seem to be working anymore.
I tried deleting node_modules and installing again but that didn't work. I deleted the whole project and recloned it, still same but other backend projects are working fine.
  "name": "mykrogrid-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register ./index.ts",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "build": "npm install && tsc && tsc-alias && npm run copy-assets",
    "postinstall": "npm run generate --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma",
    "post_install": "npm run migrate && npm run dp:push && npm run generate",
    "db:deploy": "npx prisma deploy",
    "migrate": "npx prisma migrate dev --name init-db",
    "generate": "npx prisma generate",
    "prod:start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "db:push": "npx prisma db push",
    "studio": "npx prisma studio",
    "copy-assets": "cp -r ./views ./assets dist",
    "lint:ts": "ESLINT_USE_FLAT_CONFIG=false eslint --config eslint.config.js .",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.5",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "^17.1.9",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^22.1.0",
    "@types/node-forge": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/node-schedule": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "flutterwave-node-v3-withtypes": "^1.0.11",
    "prisma": "^6.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.7",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.705.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.699.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.699.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sts": "^3.699.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-timestream-query": "^3.699.0",
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "@hyperdx/node-opentelemetry": "^0.8.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^6.0.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^7.1.2",
    "express-validation": "^4.1.0",
    "flutterwave-node-v3": "^1.1.6",
    "geolib": "^3.3.4",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "node-schedule": "^2.1.1",
    "redis": "^4.6.8",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "sql-bricks": "^3.0.1",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "twilio": "^4.19.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "winston": "^3.11.0"
  }
}```


Help us help you - share your package.json file

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command Please ALWAYS search this site for the error message before creating a new post, as chances are extremely good that it has been asked about before.

@KenWhite I already did, but there was only one related. I didn't find any adequate answer there.

They don't have to be directly related. They contain information which can be applied to your issue and resolve it. Read more than one. When you ask How can I add the integer variables y and z, the answer to How can I add the integer variables a and b has the solution, even though the variable names are different.

I get you. Just that I've tried every possible solution from what I've seen so far, and none of them seems to solve my issue.
